convention for http blocks in the new nginx configuration file convention
I have been using and installing nginx from ppa:ondrej/nginx on Ubuntu
In the /etc/nginx/conf.d folder I have several configurations in the http block such as log format, geoip2, etc. so that they can be available on all virtual hosts
In the main nginx configuration file:
...
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
...

which means that it first adds all the conf.d files and then the virtual host files
Regardless of the name of the files in conf.d, all the configurations will be available in the server blocks in the virtual host
I am restructuring the systems and scripts to bring them all to a general convention
Now I install nginx from the official page and I see that the sites-* folders are not there and the virtual host configuration is in the conf.d folder
...
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
...

Is there a convention to put all my files in conf.d and have them work correctly?

“The Ubuntu” convention for web servers  is as far as I know, for packages and administrators alike, to create configuration file snippets in conf-available and virtual hosts in sites-available and enable/disable them by creating/removing symlinks in ??-enabled subdirectories that get included in the main Apache or nginx config file. But what people do in their Personal Package Archives is AFAIK much more open to their own personal preferences and not enforced by Ubuntu coding/packaging standards so that can indeed be different. In the end: do what works for you and your team

Debian/Ubuntu and nginx's official repo have different opinions on configuration layout. But you could use whatever you want.
